# Is it correct to call router.navigate inside Guard.CanActivate method?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a project with ngrx store - with all its related entities (effects, reducers, actions).
Most of them are Login/Logout/LoginSuccess/LoginRedirect things, really simple ones.

In our project we have roles of different types (admin, candidate, manager, etc.). What I need to implement  is different home pages for different roles. I have a login/loginSuccess actions/reducers/effects that look like this:

Some code listings:
**Effects:**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LoginPageActions.login),
      map((action) => action.credentials),
      exhaustMap((auth: Credentials) =>
        this.authService.login(auth).pipe(
          map((user) => AuthApiActions.loginSuccess({ user, redirect: true })),
          catchError((error) => of(AuthApiActions.loginFailure({ error })))
        )
      )
    )
  );

loginSuccess$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthApiActions.loginSuccess),
        tap((props) => {
          switch (Object.keys(props.user.user.role)[0]) {
            case 'candidate':
              this.router.navigate(['/main-user'])
              console.log('redirect to candidate')
              break
            case 'admin':
              this.router.navigate(['/main-admin'])
              console.log('redirect to admin')
              break
          }
          // return !!props.redirect && this.router.navigate(['/'])
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

You may notice in loginSuccess effect I am making router redirection based on user Role. Is that fine or terrible practice? I need my app to load different home pages after user has logged in, I can't think of any other place to realize it. Would be perfect if I can load different components in routing module like this:

```js
{
    path: 'home',
    if (fromAuth.selectRole == 'admin')
      component: HomePageAdmin
    else if (fromAuth.selectRole == 'candidate')
      component: HomePageCandidate
}
```

Because I would need to use different header components (with different menu items) as well in future

Some reducer listings:
**Reducers:**

```js
export const loginPageFeatureKey = 'loginPage';

export interface State {
  error: string | null;
  pending: boolean;
}

export const initialState: State = {
  error: null,
  pending: false,
};

export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(LoginPageActions.login, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    error: null,
    pending: true,
  })),

  on(AuthApiActions.loginSuccess, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    error: null,
    pending: false,
  })),
  on(AuthApiActions.loginFailure, (state, { error }) => ({
    ...state,
    error,
    pending: false,
  }))
);
```

Nothing special as you can see.

Is it correct to make redirections in Route Guards? I have read many articles on how to implement Role based routing and many of articles were talking about CanActivate method. So I did redirection there as well. Only big difference to my situation was that I am retrieving role of user from the store by selector, while in articles it was done via service. Is that correct to get user Role via selector if I have that Role data in my store or may be i should refactor it via service (break store state then?)? You can see below how Role selector (selectRole) is implemented (I don't like it).

**Selectors listings:**

```js
import * as fromAuth from './auth.reducer';
import * as fromLoginPage from './login-page.reducer';

export const authFeatureKey = 'auth';

export interface AuthState {
  [fromAuth.statusFeatureKey]: fromAuth.State;
  [fromLoginPage.loginPageFeatureKey]: fromLoginPage.State;
}

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  [authFeatureKey]: AuthState;
}

// tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
export function reducers(state: AuthState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return combineReducers({
    [fromAuth.statusFeatureKey]: fromAuth.reducer,
    [fromLoginPage.loginPageFeatureKey]: fromLoginPage.reducer,
  })(state, action);
}

export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<State, AuthState>(
  authFeatureKey
);

export const selectAuthStatusState = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state) => state.status
);
export const selectUser = createSelector(
  selectAuthStatusState,
  fromAuth.getUser
);

export const selectRole = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  (user) => {
    if(user)
      return Object.keys(user.user.role)[0]
    return undefined
  }
)

export const selectLoggedIn = createSelector(selectUser, (user) => !!user);

export const selectLoginPageState = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state) => state.loginPage
);
export const selectLoginPageError = createSelector(
  selectLoginPageState,
  fromLoginPage.getError
);
export const selectLoginPagePending = createSelector(
  selectLoginPageState,
  fromLoginPage.getPending
);
```

And finally. RedirectGuardService that is supposed to redirect when user routing pages.

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.store.pipe(
      select(fromAuth.selectRole),
      filter(role => !!role),
      map((role) => {
        switch (role) {
          case 'admin':
            this.router.navigate(['/main-admin'])
            break
          case 'candidate':
            this.router.navigate(['/main-user'])
            break
        }
        return true
      }),
      take(1),
    )

  }
```

I don't like that CanActivate supposed to return true/false instead I just make router.navigate and it never gets to returns. Is that correct? If not, how do I implement routing redirection while getting Role from store by selector **selectRole**. Some pseudo code would be a nice example.

Answer (score 2):

From 7.1 Angular version, you can return an [UrlTree](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree) in the canActivate method. This is the best way to redirect in the canActivate method.

The easiest way to create the UrlTree is by using the parseUrl(). For example:

```
this.router.parseUrl('/main-admin')
```

> Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a route can be activated. If all guards return true, navigation continues. If any guard returns false, navigation is cancelled. If any guard returns a UrlTree, the current navigation is cancelled and a new navigation begins to the UrlTree returned from the guard.

[About CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: yeap, ty for answer, i read about it. Still, a question remains in my mind. Is that okay to redirect in CanActivate Guard, while it's purpose is to Activate/Not Activate route based on inner logic ?

Comment: Yes, because it's an extra option. It cancels navigation and navigates to another route where we can have access.

Comment: I had the same apprehension as @Anton and found this answer. I personally prefer to return the UrlTree so that the routing infrastructure can best deal with it instead of causing the current routing flow to be interrupted. Any pointers?

Comment: You can do it. Best practice would be to return `UrlTree`. Give that a shot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713233/7952244